# Glow is synonymous with bloom

Tags: feature-request, tags

15 questions on [glow](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glow) and 12 on [bloom](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloom) while they describe the same effect, only bloom has a tag-wiki description.

Comment: Does anybody else have an opinion on this? Pro or con?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a rather old question, but nothing appears to have been done about it yet.

I would argue that they should both be synonyms of [graphic-effects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-effects), [glow](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glow) and [bloom](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloom) seem a bit too 'low-level'  to be useful in their own right. Also 15 questions is a pretty low number to be a reasonable categorization.

I would expect someone who was interested/knows a lot about bloom effects would also be interested/know a lot about glow effects.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they're synonymous.

When I think of Bloom I think of Wikipedia's definition

> The effect produces fringes (or feathers) of light extending from the borders of bright areas in an image, contributing to the illusion of an extremely bright light overwhelming the camera or eye capturing the scene.

Where as I think of glow as just making something emit light.

I like to think of it as you can make an object glow in a game, then you can apply bloom to it.

Comment: So you want glow to be synonymous for emissive textures?

Comment: Possibly. A texture could produce light that could be used in lighting equations, i.e a object textured with a green emissive texture goes near a white wall it will light the wall green. You could then apply bloom to it to create the illusion of light overwhelming the camera.

Comment: Glowing could also be interpreted as putting an outline around a character, which doesn't really have anything to do with lighting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they should be merged.  <EOM>

Just kidding; not end of the message.  I just don't have any particular justification for my opinion other than generally disagreeing with the other answer.  Even if there is some slight difference in some definition, on this site they are used interchangeably.